# How to make DFDL model to JSON data?

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I learn App Connect Enterprise v11 and try to make a DFDL Schema for JSON data and I do not know how. I successfully made a Schema for Record-Oriented-Text like the below but do not know how to do it for JSON.

Record-Oriented-Text example:

```
Delivery+++XYZ123ABC+++My order was delivered in time, but the package was torn|C01-COM684a2da-384+++Your complaint has been received
```

JSON example:

```
{
"YourComplaint": {
    "Type": "Delivery",
    "Reference": "XYZ123ABC",
    "Text": "My order was delivered in time, but the package was torn"
},
"Reply": {
    "OurReference": "C01-COM684a2da-384",
    "Text": "Your complaint has been received"
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create a DFDL schema for JSON data. ACE can parse JSON without any help from a schema. You should use the JSON parser/domain for JSON (just as you use the XMLNSC domain for XML).

If you need to output your record-oriented data as JSON then you need to map from InputRoot.DFDL to OutputRoot.JSON. You may also need to set some field types to ensure that the JSON data looks exactly how you need it.